# How to make a squared image to a round image on Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to make a round image from a squared image on a Windows phone? I have a lot of images which should be displayed as a circle. But how can I do this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In XAML you want to make the circle using an Ellipse control. Then give it an ImageBrush fill.

```
<Ellipse Height="100" Width="100">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="YourImage.png"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: FYI, this does not preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: Use `<ImageBrush ImageSource="YourImage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>` to preserve aspect ratio and clip.

Comment: Good point, @Nateous! Thank you. And if you're scaling, don't forget `<Ellipse Height="100" Width="100" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">`, otherwise it will look ugly.

Answer (score 16):

My idea is very simple:

```
<Image Source="ImagePath" Width="326" Height="188">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="170,90" RadiusX="90" RadiusY="90" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Or you can apply an OpacityMask to an Image to create a variety of opacity-related photo masking

```
<Image Source="ImagePath" >
       <Image.OpacityMask>
              <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">                          
                            <GradientStop Color="#ffffffff" Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="0.8" />
               </RadialGradientBrush>
       </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

Comment: none of the two options work on Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image.Clip but i prefer the @robwirving solution. But you need to choice now!
Information here => [http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)